# reading structured binary data in python3.6 using struct

Tags: python, struct, binary, ascii, python-3.6

I really tried to look for this doubt in many ways but maybe since I never worked with binary files before I don't have any idea what the keywords to search similar things to help me out. That's why I am asking here.

So, I have a file:

```
path = 'myPath/file.pd0'
in_file = open(path, "rb")
read_file = in_file.read()
type(read_file)
```

when I try to check what is inside read_file I get:

```
b'\x7f\x7f\xcc\x05\x00\x0f$\x00`\x00\xa2\x00$\x02\xe6\x02\xa8\x03\xd0\x032\x04d\x04\x96\x04\xa6\x04\xe0\x04'
```

The type of read_file is bytes. When I try to use struct since it is the function people suggest I get the following error:

```
import struct
struct.unpack('hhl', read_file[0:30])

error: unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes
```

No matter what fmt I get unpack requires a buffer of n bytes.

The file structure that I am trying to read is defined as follow:

HEADER
(6 BYTES + [2 x No. OF DATA TYPES])

FIXED LEADER DATA
(60 BYTES)

VARIABLE LEADER DATA
(66 BYTES)

CORRELATION MAGNITUDE
(2 BYTES + 4 BYTES PER DEPTH CELL)

Any idea how I could start reading these bytes using struct or something similar in python?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`unpack()` expects bytes which are the exact length of the format described by its first argument.
The format string `'hhl'` describes data of 16 bytes (on your machine - see below), so you must pass a byte string of 16.
If you want to parse only part of the bytes, you can do this:

```
fmt = 'hhl'
size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
struct.unpack(fmt, data[:size])
```

Additionally, your format string doesn't have a [byte order, size and alignment specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). It is assumed to be "native" by default. This means your code is system-dependent, which is probably not what you want for parsing a file format.
You might need different alignments for different parts of the file.